# New transaction if the last transaction is still pending

Tags: pending, address, address-reuse

I just tried to send some IOTAs to a complete new adress in my desktop wallet. After the proof of work the Desktopwallet (2.5 4 - IRI 1.4.1.2) wrote a warning because of reusing an adress. Has this something to do with another transaction in my wallet that is still pending? Does that mean I always have to finish the first transaction before I can do the next transaction?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending a transaction, and another transaction of the wallet is still pending, you will usually have to wait.

In case your first transaction does not exactly use up the amount of your first few addresses, the change will be sent to a new address of your wallet, so that you do not have to reuse the key of the address for spending the second part. As long as this part is not confirmed, you will not be able to issue a new transaction that tries to spend that part. This will probably not change in a future wallet (except they add some checks to delay the new transaction until it gets confirmed)?

Also, the current wallet does not take pending transactions into account when computing address balances (neither incoming nor outgoing ones), so it will try to spend the exact same money again with the new transaction (resulting in the error you are seeing here).

A future wallet version will hopefully handle the second case better; for the first case, I would doubt it. On the other hand, I hope that the new wallet will support transactions (or rather transaction bundles) with more than one outgoing payment, so that if you want to do multiple payments at the same time, you can do them in one step and only have one bundle you have to wait to get confirmed (like some Bitcoin wallets handle it too).